# validacion de laravel antes de mostrar sweatalert

Tags: jquery, laravel

estoy trabajando con laravel, tengo un formulario desde el cual voy a guardar esos datos en mi base de datos, lo que necesito es que al momento de hacer el submit del formulario se muestre una ventana de confirmacion (con sweatalert) donde el suaurio confirma que esta seguro de enviar la informacion, hasta ahora consigo mostrar la ventana de confirmacion, pero aparte el formulario tiene validaciones (las que manejo desde el controlador)

Logre hacer que se muestren las validaciones, entonces si pasa las validaciones me muestra la confirmacion de sweatalert, pero ahora el problema es que esta enviando el email y haciendo el insert aun sin hacer click en el boton aceptar del sweatalert

eL JAVASCRIPT lo tengo asi:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
  let formSubmitted = false;

  $('#form-solicitud').submit(function (event) {
    if (formSubmitted) {
      return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    const emailValue = $('#email').val();
      Swal.fire({
            title: '¿Estás seguro?',
            text: 'Se enviará un email a ' + emailValue,
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Sí, enviar',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
              formSubmitted = true;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/sistema/solicitud/guardar',
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
      },
      data: $('#form-solicitud').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error de validación',
            html: formatValidationErrors(data.errors),
          });
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr) {
        var errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
        // Verificar si hay mensajes de error
        if (errors) {
            // Mostrar el mensaje de error en la interfaz de usuario
            formatValidationErrors(errors);
            $('#error-container').show();
        }else{
          // Si no hay mensajes de error estructurados, mostrar el mensaje como texto
          Swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Error',
              text: xhr.responseText || 'Se produjo un error al procesar la solicitud. Por favor, inténtalo nuevamente.',
          });
        }
      },
    });
              console.log('presione acpetar');
              //$('#form-solicitud').data('submit-scheduled', true).submit();
            }
          });
  });

  // Agregamos un listener para evitar el envío automático después de la confirmación
  $('#form-solicitud').on('submit', function (event) {
    if (!$(this).data('submit-scheduled')) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  function formatValidationErrors(errors) {
    let html = '<h5>Se encontraron los siguientes errores:</h5>';

    if (typeof errors === 'string') {
      html += errors;
    } else if (typeof errors === 'object') {
      $.each(errors, function (key, errorList) {
        $.each(errorList, function (index, error) {
          html += `${error}<br>`;
        });
      });
    }

    $('#error-container').html(html);
  }
});
```

y la funcion en el controlador:

```
  $rules = [
            'nombres' => 'required|max:50',
            'ape_pat' => 'required|max:50',
            'rut' => 'required|max:25',
            'institucion' => 'required',
            'cargo' => 'required',
            'unidad' => 'required',
            'jornada' => 'required',
            'telefono' => 'required|max:9',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:90',
            'fecha_realizacion_visita' => 'required',
            'hora_ingreso' => 'required',
            'hora_salida' => 'required',
            'movilizacion' => 'required',
            'motivo_visita' => 'required',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'nombres.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Su nombre(s)',
            'nombres.max' =>'Maximo 50 caracteres',
            'ape_pat.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Apellido Paterno',
            'ape_pat.max' =>'Maximo 50 caracteres',
            'rut.required' =>'Debe Ingresar N° Rut o Doc.Identidad',
            'institucion.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Institución',
            'cargo.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Cargo',
            'unidad.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Unidad',
            'jornada.required' =>'Debe Seleccionar Jornada',
            'telefono.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Telefono (Ej:911223344)',
            'telefono.max' =>'Maximo 9 numeros',
            'email.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Correo Electronico',
            'email.max' =>'Maximo 90 caracteres',
            'email.email'=> 'Formato de Email no valido',
            'fecha_realizacion_visita.required' =>'Debe Seleccionar Fecha de la Visita',
            'hora_ingreso.required' =>'Debe indicar Hora de Acceso',
            'hora_salida.required' =>'Debe indicar Hora de Salida',
            'movilizacion.required' =>'Debe Indicar si requiere movilizacion',
            'motivo_visita.required' =>'Debe Seleccionar Motivo Visita',
        ];


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            //dd($validator->errors());
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        //return response()->json(['message' => 'Solicitud guardada correctamente'], 200);

        try {
             //Insertar en tabla solicitud_accesos
         $solicitud = new solicitudAcceso();
         $solicitud->nombres = $request->get('nombres');
         $solicitud->ape_pat = $request->get('ape_pat');
         $solicitud->ape_mat = $request->get('ape_mat');
         $solicitud->rut = $request->get('rut');
         $solicitud->institucion = $request->get('institucion');
         $solicitud->cargo = $request->get('cargo');
         $solicitud->unidad = strtoupper($request->get('unidad'));
         $solicitud->jornada = $request->get('jornada');
         $solicitud->telefono = $request->get('telefono');
         $solicitud->email = $request->get('email');
         $solicitud->motivo_visita = $request->get('motivo_visita');
         $solicitud->detalle_motivo = $request->get('detalle_visita');
         $solicitud->fecha_realizacion_visita = $request->get('fecha_realizacion_visita');
         $solicitud->hora_ingreso = $request->get('hora_ingreso');
         $solicitud->hora_salida = $request->get('hora_salida');
         $solicitud->movilizacion = $request->get('movilizacion');
         $solicitud->fecha_movilizacion = $request->get('fecha_movilizacion');
         $solicitud->movilizacion_propia = $request->get('movilizacion_propia');
         $solicitud->status = 0;
         $solicitud->validacion_ingreso = 0;
         $solicitud->save();

         $nombre_asistente = $request->nombres_asistente;
         $ape_pat_asistente = $request->ape_pat_asistente;
         $ape_mat_asistente = $request->ape_mat_asistente;
         $rut_asistente = $request->rut_asistente;
         $telefono_asistente = $request->telefono_asistente;
         $email_asistente = $request->email_asistente;
         $ingreso = 0;
         $insertado = 0;

    //Obtiene las Variables para isnertar asistentes
         if (!empty($nombre_asistente) && !empty($ape_pat_asistente) && !empty($ape_mat_asistente) && !empty($rut_asistente) && !empty($telefono_asistente) && !empty($email_asistente)) {

     $asistentes = [];

     for ($i = 0; $i < count($nombre_asistente); $i++) {
         $asistentes[] = [
             'nombres' => $nombre_asistente[$i],
             'ape_pat' => $ape_pat_asistente[$i],
             'ape_mat' => $ape_mat_asistente[$i],
             'rut' => $rut_asistente[$i],
             'telefono' => $telefono_asistente[$i],
             'email' => $email_asistente[$i],
             'ingreso' => $ingreso,
             'insertado' => $insertado,
             'solicitud_acceso_id' => $solicitud->id
         ];
     }

     // Perform the bulk insert
     DB::table('asistentes')->insert($asistentes);
 }

         //Enviar Email al Administrador
       $dataAdministrativo = [
             'nombre' => $solicitud->nombres,
             'ape_pat' => $solicitud->ape_pat,
             'email' => $solicitud->email,
             'fecha' => $solicitud->fecha_realizacion_visita,
             'motivo' => $solicitud->motivo_visita,
             'hora' => $solicitud->hora_ingreso,
             'unidad' => $solicitud->unidad,
             'institucion' => $solicitud->institucion,
             'rut' => $solicitud->rut,
             'id' => $solicitud->id,
             'asunto' => "Solicitud Acceso NHQ $solicitud->nombres $solicitud->ape_pat"
         ];

         $email_administrativo = "ezequiel.almonacid@gmail.com";

         Mail::to($email_administrativo)->send(new SolicitudAdministrador ($dataAdministrativo));


         //Envia comprobante de solicitud al Usuario
         $comprobanteUsuario = [
             'nombre' => $solicitud->nombres,
             'ape_pat' => $solicitud->ape_pat,
             'email' => $solicitud->email,
             'fecha' => $solicitud->fecha_realizacion_visita,
             'motivo' => $solicitud->motivo_visita,
             'hora' => $solicitud->hora_ingreso,
             'unidad' => $solicitud->unidad,
             'institucion' => $solicitud->institucion,
             'rut' => $solicitud->rut,
             'id' => $solicitud->id,
             'movilizacion' => $solicitud->movilizacion,
             'fecha_movilizacion' => $solicitud->fecha_movilizacion,
             'asunto' => "Comprobante Solicitud Acceso NHQ N°$solicitud->id"
         ];

         $email_solicitante = $solicitud->email;

         Mail::to($email_solicitante)->send(new ComprobanteSolicitudUsuario ($comprobanteUsuario));
            // Respuesta exitosa
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Solicitud guardada correctamente'], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Manejar errores de inserción
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error al guardar la solicitud'], 500);
        }
```

Comment: En el ajax de jquery estás tratando de manejar el error en la propiedad `success` en vez de en la propiedad `error`. La respuesta de laravel va a tener staus 422, por lo que va a entrar en `error` y no en `success`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias, logre hacer que funcione la validacion y si pasa las validaciones que muestre el sweatalert de confirmacion pero como comento en el post, esta haciendo el insert y enviando el mail aun sin presionar el boton de confirmacion

Comment: Ah ok, entonces, el swal que pide confirmación tendría que ir en la siguiente línea del `prevent.default()` y la llamafa ajax en la función `then` de ese swal dentro del `if`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ hice el cambio al menos como entendi que me recomendaste pero no se envia el formulario ahora jeje

Comment: Me referia al evento `on('submit'`. Ahi te escribi una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

El evento `$('#form-solicitud').submit...` no es necesario.

La confirmacion la tendrias que hacer antes de que se envie, por ejemplo en `$('#form-solicitud').on('submit', function (event) {...`.

Apenas se quiera enviar el form, haces el `event.preventDefault();` e inmediatamente le pides la confirmacion.

Si el usuario confirma, lanzas la llamada ajax que envia el formulario.

Luego el manejo de errores lo haces en la propiedad `error` de la funcion $.ajax`.

```js
// Agregamos un listener para evitar el envío por defecto y pedimos confirmacion
$('#form-solicitud').on('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Estás seguro?',
    text: 'Se enviará un email',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Sí, enviar',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      console.log('Dijo que Si')
      // Hacemos la llamada ajax,
      postForm();
    } else {
      console.log('Cancelo')
    }
  });
});

function postForm() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://httpbin.org/status/422',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
      // Laravel respondio que todo ok.
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.log('xhr.status: ', xhr.status);
      if(xhr.status == 422) {
        // Es un error de validacion. Maneja los mensajes de error.
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Error de validación',
          //html: formatValidationErrors(data.errors),
        });
      }
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<form id="form-solicitud">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: gracias, estuve probando pero de esta manera ya no hace la validacion del formulario :(

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid No entiendo a que te refieres con _"ya no hace la validacion del formulario"_, tendrias que ser mas especifico, o actualizar la pregunta y explicar bien que es lo que no funciona como deberia. La validacion del formulario la hace laravel, si ya estaba funcionando, deberia seguir funcionando. La llamada ajax puse una de ejemplo nomas, no es para copiar y pegar, adaptala a tus necesidades (con tu url y los datos del form)